# LibGdx - How can I resize my game window while keeping the aspect ratio?

Tags: java, libgdx, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

Right now, I'm trying to code something that makes it where when the window is resized with the mouse, it will stay at a 16:9 aspect ratio. I'd like to have the code for this inside of my desktop launcher (I'm only compiling to desktop) but I'm also ok with doing it in my game file with `public void resize()` if I have to. I'm using Libgdx 3 so I can't use stuff like `cfg.height` but I'm curious if I can do it using `config.setWindowSizeLimits()` and just change the boundaries when necessary. If I'm missing something and there actually is a way to get the window's dimensions inside of desktop launcher that would be very good to know.

Comment: Which layout are you using?

Comment: Right now I'm using a FitViewport but I'm still at a point where I can change it. I'm kind of past my original idea now but it would still be really good to have an answer. Just to be clear, I want to control the ratio of the window, not the contents inside it.

Comment: Also, for whoever it might help in the future, I found that you can get the height, width, and refresh rate of the current monitor using `Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.getDisplayMode().refreshRate;` where refreshRate can be changed to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FitViewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/FitViewport.html). This will not fix the ratio of the window itself, but it `keeps the aspect ratio by scaling the world up to fit the screen, adding black bars (letterboxing) for the remaining space`.

You can use it like this:

```
public void initializeCameraAndViewport() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, camera);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

It will make the screen look like this:

[image: fit viewport]

See [the libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#fitviewport) for a more detailed description of viewports.